# React Native Open Google Photos

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to open the photos app from react native using Linking library.
I have tried both the methods below but none is working.

```
    Linking.openURL('photos.google.com://IMG_20170708_110810855.jpg')
    Linking.openURL('photos://IMG_20170708_110810855.jpg')
```

Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Any update on this ?